# Unable change the Date format in ng-model of angular JS?

Tags: angularjs

In my web app am using ng-repeat to show the data of some customer. In that list each customer has DOB field. If they want to change the DOB then they can change using date picker. I giving the date format as **yyyy/MM/dd**. While showing the data initially am using `$filter` to format the date but if the user changes the date again am unable to format it. Below is my code, plz check.

**html**

```
<div ng-repeat="panellist in panelistDataList | filter: headerObj.search | SortListOrderByDate:'Date':true  track by panellist.PanellistID">
        <input type="text" name="DOB" class="transparent-textbox" required ng-model="panellist.DOB" ng-click="showCalender()"/>
        <span class="leftPadding">
            <i class="fa fa-calendar fa-1" ng-click="showCalender()"></i>
        </span>
        <div class="DOBPicker picker">
            <div class="datepickermodal">
                <time-date-picker ng-model="panellist.DOB" toggle-calendar="toggleCal(newFoo)" ng-style="{display: (calendar.showStart == true ? 'block' : 'none')}" max-date="calendar.toDay" start-date="calendar.toDay"></time-date-picker>
            </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

I tried with doing like this `ng-model="panellist.DOB | date : 'yyyy/MM/dd'"`
It is working but in console it shows error that it is not proper format.

Comment: create a plunker for your issue

Answer (score 0):

In your controller you may

`$scope.panellist.DOB = new Date($scope.panellist.DOB)`

to make it date